# Are there temperature, energy in mathematics

Tags: soft-question, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Temperature, energy, entropy, etc. are quantities in statistical mechanics, and are properties of specific physical systems.

However, recently I discovered that random variables have "entropy" $S$:

> $\text{S}(X) = \mathbb{E}\left[ - \log p(X) \right] = -\sum_x p(x) \log(p(x)) $

This makes me wonder, do random variables/distributions also have defined terms like temperature and energy?

They usually hold the relation: $\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial U} = \dfrac 1T$

Comment: You find a discussion about this [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141321/what-is-the-conceptual-difference-between-gibbs-and-boltzmann-entropies). In short : the step from Shannon entropy (that you wrote above), aka, Information entropy (and up to a constant equal to Gibbs entropy) to the thermodynamic Boltzmann entropy is not immediate. It has been the source of much confusion and controversy. See for instance [Landauer's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle).

Comment: Some optimization procedures include a tuneable "temperature" parameter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entropy in one branch of mathematics, information theory, is a measure of the information content of a message. It's not actually related to the entropy in physics except by analogy. A completely ordered message consisting of just ones or just zeros has no entropy, whereas a totally random unpredictable message has high entropy.

As far as I know, there is no equivalent use of the words "temperature" or "energy" in information theory, for example the "temperature" of an information source or the amount of "energy" in a message.

Even if these terms were used, they would be analogies to physics concepts rather than meaningful terms.